# compare documents using most similar method

Tags: nlp, gensim

I am able to build the model using the built-in lee_background corpus. But when I try to compare using most_similar method, I get an error.

```
lee_train_file = '/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/test/test_data/lee_background.cor'

train_corpus=list()
with open(lee_train_file) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        train_corpus.append(gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(line), [i]))

model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(vector_size=48, min_count=2, epochs=40)
model.build_vocab(train_corpus)
model.wv.vocab['penalty'].count
model.train(train_corpus, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.epochs)

line="""
dummy text here...
"""

inferred_vector=model.infer_vector(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(line) )

model.docvecs.most_similar(inferred_vector, topn=3)
```

I tried this with list(inferred_vector) but still getting an error.

> TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not iterable

I am trying to compare the dummy text with the corpus and find if the entry already exist in the data file.

---

Update:
Instead of list(inferred_vector) I need to use [inferred_vector]. This has solved my problem. But ever-time I run this code, I get different similar documents. How is this possible?

```
line="""
The national executive of the strife-torn Democrats last night appointed little-known West Australian senator Brian Greig 
as interim leader--a shock move likely to provoke further conflict between the party's senators and its organisation. 
In a move to reassert control over the party's seven senators, the national executive last night rejected Aden Ridgeway's 
bid to become interim leader, in favour of Senator John, a supporter of deposed leader Natasha Stott Despoja and an outspoken 
gay rights activist.
"""

inferred_vector=model.infer_vector(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(line))

model.docvecs.most_similar([inferred_vector], topn=5)
```

Sometimes I get this list and the list keeps changing everytime I run the code even if there is no change in the model.

```
[(151, 0.5980586409568787),
 (74, 0.5736572742462158),
 (106, 0.5714541077613831),
 (249, 0.5695925951004028),
 (209, 0.5642371773719788)]

[(249, 0.5727256536483765),
 (151, 0.5725511312484741),
 (74, 0.5711895823478699),
 (106, 0.5583171248435974),
 (292, 0.5491517782211304)]
```

As a matter of fact, the first line in training corpus is 99% similar to this line because only 1 word is changed. Surprisingly the document_id 1 is nowhere in the top 5 list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dummy line should be selected from lee_background.cor and not from lee.cor
The model text will match with training corpus and not with test corpus.